# Apache-Forbidden 403-Works when Apache is off-Others on LAN can't connect

Tags: apache, web

I just downloaded Apache. I changed the index.html file to my own. The file is fine, no problems. But when I try accessing it through Apache I get Forbidden 403.( I'm am using the computer Apache is running on.) But when I turn exit Apache, the html file loads perfectly. I also am having trouble getting others on the network to access the file. They return "Can't find server". Any Help would be great. Also I change the httpd.conf file based on what I found by researching. Here it is [http.conf](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zaJiR3YjarhZBjYkzaqrukWvPMYO917dNkg_4FaNA9k/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your document root out of Program Files and into a less restricted directory.

(There might be other permissions issues, too, but this is likely one of them.)

Update:

You will also need to add an exception to your firewall for inbound TCP traffic on port 80.

Comment: Okay, let me know if you run into trouble and I'll elaborate.

Comment: What happens when you try to access it on a remote computer?

Comment: Check your firewalls, and ensure that you have the right IP address.  Try using the IP address instead of the name of the computer if you haven't already.

Comment: I turned off my firewall and now it works on another LAN computer. Is there a way to avoid turning it off?

Comment: Yes.  You need to add an exception to your firewall for port 80 (TCP).

Comment: Also I changed back my httpd to the default, but changed the directory like you suggested.

Comment: I added an exception for Apache html server. now its not working on LAN computer

Comment: wait is that exception for the windows firewall or the router's. and it's NOT working on LAN

Comment: i port forwarded port 80 tcp on my router for the servers IP. still not working

Comment: Oh, it's not working, ha.  Windows Firewall.  Your router, too, if you want to make it accessible via WAN, but that also requires port forwarding, which is a completely separate issue.

Comment: how do i do that on windows 7?

Comment: That's a separate question.  You should research that on your own.

Comment: i'm new to this but do is there a way to recognize you to stackoverflow? press checkmark? or something?

Comment: If you mean mark my answer as correct, you've already done that (thanks!).  If you mean follow me on StackOverflow, you can bookmark the link to my profile.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! I spent 3 hours trying different programs, editing files, etc. Now I can finish my project! thanks again!